# Low FPS in Counter-Strike: Global Offensive on Steam in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, games, steam

I have a strange problem, let me explain, my PC hardware is:

- Intel Core i7-6700HQ
- NVIDIA GTX 950M
- 8GB of RAM.

I start the game Counter-Strike: Global Offensive on Steam and all is OK, in 2 minutes of playing the FPS falls down from ca. 120 to 20. After changing something in graphic settings the FPS goes to 50-60 and again and again. Maybe my PC is to bad or I don't know, What should I do?

Please see the image for a better reference of my issue.

Comment: Same issue with LoL